# python code for irs_reward(money_recovered)

Tags: python

- IRS informants are paid cash rewards based on the value of the money recovered. If the information was specific enough to lead to a recovery, the informant receives
- 10% of the first $75,000 plus
- 5% of the next $25,000  plus
- 1% of the remainder up to a maximum reward of $50,000.
- The following function accepts the amount of money recovered and returns the reward.
- to run tests: python3 -m doctest irs_reward.py -v

  ```
  '''def irs_reward(money_recovered):

  IRS informants are paid cash rewards based on the value of the money recovered

  calculate reward amount from money recovered

  args:
   money_recovered (float): dollar value of money recovered

  returns:
    the dollar value of the reward (float)

  formula:
    10% of the first $75k
    + 5% of the next $25k
    + 1% of the rest, up to max total reward of $50k

    examples/doctests:

    no money recovered
    >>> round(irs_reward(0), 2)
    0.0

    $75k recovered
    >>> round(irs_reward(75000), 2)
    7500.0

    $95k recovered
    >>> round(irs_reward(95000), 2)
    8500.0

    $200,000 recovered
    >>> round(irs_reward(200000), 2)
    9750.0

    $42 milliion recovered, max out at $50k reward
    >>> round(irs_reward(42000000), 2)
    50000.0

    # TO DO: Add your code here #
    # ========================= #

   return
  ```
- Can someone help me with the code. I have tried 5 to 6 times and finally closed out the program and did not save it.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn how this works, not just get people to do your homework for you, but here goes:

```
def calculate_reward(money_recovered):
    reward = 0
    if money_recovered >= 4125000:
        reward = 50000
    elif money_recovered >= 100000:
        reward = (money_recovered - 100000)/100 + 8750
    elif money_recovered >= 75000:
        reward = (money_recovered - 75000)/20 + 7500
    else:
        reward = money_recovered/10
    return reward
```

The reason for the number 4125000 is because thats the number needed to make the total reward 50k. It is 10% of 75k + 5% of 25k + 1% of the rest, which makes the remaining 41.25k.

The next barrier is 100k since that is 25k + 75k, so things above that but below 4125000 get taxed 1%, and each time we check for the money being over a barrier we add the max they received from lower amounts.